# jsp: javascript template literal not working

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, ecmascript-6, template-literals

I tried useing template literal

expected result was 'TEST DATA TEST'

but, it doesn't work

How to use it on jsp?

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<script>
var t = "TEST";

console.log(`테스트 데이터  ${t} `);
</script>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: console.log(`TEST DATA  ${t} `);

Answer (score 5):

keypoint is '\'

```html
console.log(`테스트 데이터  \${t} `);
```

Answer (score 0):

You code has two problems:

First ,you need to use `"` or `'` instead of 
`Then you need to can not set parameter in javascript side and get it via`${t}`,due to`${t}` is an EL expression

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<% String t="TEST"; %> <!-- set value in the server side -->
<script>
console.log("테스트 데이터  ${t}");
</script>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```